# Detecting when there are no Chrome Windows Open - Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a manifest v3 chrome extension and I want to use the background.js to detect if there are no chrome windows open at all. I have the following code. It sends a notification when there are tabs and even relays the number of them. When I close all tabs however I never get the other notification confirming that they are all closed. I am using this method to determine when I should send the user a chrome notification and when I should not. I don't want to send a notification if the user has a active tab open because they will be able to see the notification on the tab. I want to only send one when they wont be able to see the notification in a tab.

```
function sendNotificationIfNoWindows() {
  chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: false }, (windows) => {
    if (windows.length === 0) {
      chrome.notifications.create({
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('icons/logo.png'),
        title: 'No Open Windows',
        message: 'There are no open Chrome windows.',
      });
    } else {
      chrome.notifications.create({
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('icons/logo.png'),
        title: 'No Open Windows',
        message: 'There are open Chrome windows.',
      });
    }
  });
}
setInterval(sendNotificationIfNoWindows, 5000); // Check every 5 seconds.
```

Comment: Remove setInterval and use chrome.windows.onRemoved listener. Note that normally the browser fully exits when the last window is closed, so this will work only in Mac or if your extension has `"permissions":["background"]`

Comment: @wOxxOm permissions: background did it!. Thanks